# <meta charset=“utf-8”> or <meta http-equiv=“Content-Type”>, which should I use?

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags

In order to define charset for HTML 5 doctype, which notation should I use?

1. Short:

   ```
   meta charset="utf-8"
   ```
2. Long:

   ```
   meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

See the section [*Specifying the document’s character encoding*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#specifying-the-documents-character-encoding) in the HTML 5.1 spec:

> […] using a `meta` element with a `charset` attribute or a `meta` element with an `http-equiv` attribute in the [encoding declaration state](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#statedef-http-equiv-content-type).

So both ways are fine. (But don’t use both in the same document.)